# LEFT JOIN дублирует строки

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli

Доброе время суток, пытаюсь получить значение с таблицы doctor_to_category
 (структура: doctor_category_id | doctor_id | category_id)

В следующем запросе, но если вставить LEFT JOIN doctor_to_category, то все предложения таблицы doctor_clinic_offer дублируются, как получить значение doctor_category_id каждого предложения без дублей...

```
SELECT * 
FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "doctor_clinic_offer dco 
WHERE dco.doctor_id = '" . (int)$doctor_id . "' 
  AND dco.clinic_id = '" . (int)$doctor_clinic['clinic_id'] . "' 
ORDER BY IF(special<>'',dco.special,dco.price) ASC
```

Comment: если после джойна что-то дублируется, то либо в условии джойна чего-тоне хватает, либо данные в присоединяемой таблицу с дублями

Comment: в doctor_to_category почти всегда дублируются doctor_id  и category_id...

Comment: А тогда что Вы хотите? к одной записи из `doctor_clinic_offer` присоединяются различные записи из `doctor_to_category`, и получаются несколько различных объединённых записей, содержащих информацию из обеих таблиц. Нужна только одна запись? ну так определитесь, какая одна из различных записей из `doctor_to_category` нужна, и присоединяйте только её, задавая нужные дополнительные условия в ON, либо замените таблицу на подзапрос, который оставит только одну соответствующую запись. PS. А почему LEFT? что, есть врачи без категории?

Comment: Покажите структуру всех таблиц и ваш вариант с LEFT JOIN